# What permissions are needed to create a table in DynamoDB using a lambda function written in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am currently trying to create an API that needs to be able to dynamically create tables within DynamoDB, I am receiving this error whenever I try and test it.

Currently, the role assigned to this function uses a basic execution role for lambda as well as full access to DynamoDB. Is there a role I am missing that is causing this error or is it something else entirely?

Error:

```
 {
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateTable operation: User: arn:aws:sts::**[myacctnumber]**:assumed-role/lambdaRole/myTest is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:CreateTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:**[myacctnumber]**:table/192.168.200.0/24",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/reqTest.py\", line 63, in main\n    table = db.create_table(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/resources/factory.py\", line 520, in do_action\n    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/resources/action.py\", line 83, in __call__\n    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 357, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 676, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

Program:

```html
import json, boto3, ipaddress, requests, sys, meraki, os
from ipaddress import IPv4Network

def main(event, context):
    db = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region)
    method = event['httpMethod']
    
    if method == 'GET':
    
        name = '192.168.200.0/24'
        
        table = db.create_table(
            TableName= name,
            KeySchema=[
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'CIDR',
                    'KeyType': 'HASH'  # Partition key
                },
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'availability',
                    'KeyType': 'RANGE'  # Sort key
                }
            ],
            AttributeDefinitions=[
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'CIDR',
                    'AttributeType': 'S'
                },
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'availability',
                    'AttributeType': 'S'
                },
    
            ],
            ProvisionedThroughput={
                'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
                'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
            }
        )
    
            
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': 'success'
        }
```

I found this example code across various documentations, and used it as a base, but it never mentions what permissions lambda should have to execute them properly:

```html
table = dynamodb.create_table(
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'string',
            'AttributeType': 'S'|'N'|'B'
        },
    ],
    TableName='string',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'string',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'|'RANGE'
        },
    ],
    LocalSecondaryIndexes=[
        {
            'IndexName': 'string',
            'KeySchema': [
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'string',
                    'KeyType': 'HASH'|'RANGE'
                },
            ],
            'Projection': {
                'ProjectionType': 'ALL'|'KEYS_ONLY'|'INCLUDE',
                'NonKeyAttributes': [
                    'string',
                ]
            }
        },
    ],
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes=[
        {
            'IndexName': 'string',
            'KeySchema': [
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'string',
                    'KeyType': 'HASH'|'RANGE'
                },
            ],
            'Projection': {
                'ProjectionType': 'ALL'|'KEYS_ONLY'|'INCLUDE',
                'NonKeyAttributes': [
                    'string',
                ]
            },
            'ProvisionedThroughput': {
                'ReadCapacityUnits': 123,
                'WriteCapacityUnits': 123
            }
        },
    ],
    BillingMode='PROVISIONED'|'PAY_PER_REQUEST',
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 123,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 123
    },
    StreamSpecification={
        'StreamEnabled': True|False,
        'StreamViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'|'OLD_IMAGE'|'NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES'|'KEYS_ONLY'
    },
    SSESpecification={
        'Enabled': True|False,
        'SSEType': 'AES256'|'KMS',
        'KMSMasterKeyId': 'string'
    },
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistakenly indicated a CIDR of `192.168.200.0/24` as the table name when calling CreateTable. That's not a valid table name.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, completely forgot slashes were illegal characters in the dynamodb table name. Appreciate the assist!